# How do I add a font to the Divi Wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, fonts

How do I add a font to the Divi wordPress theme? The font is from fonts.com and is called Vectora. Should I use a plugin or custom code? The site I would like to add it to is stewards.degrootdesign.com

Comment: A quick search on google returned [this tutorial page](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-fonts-in-wordpress/) as the first result.  Did you do any research before posting here?

Comment: @MTCoster This tutorial helps to add fonts to Wordpress, but not to Divi. Divi offers additional functions. For example, it offers a font selection in the module settings. How to add a new font in the selection field? The tutorial does not say anything about it.

Answer (score 4):

Best approach to override the function in child theme by simply adding this code in child theme and your font will be appear in Divi theme editor.

```
/*
 * Fonts Function for fetching all fonts.
 *
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'et_builder_get_google_fonts' ) ) :
    function et_builder_get_google_fonts() {
       $google_fonts = array(
            'customfontname' => array(
                'styles'        => '400',
                'character_set' => 'latin',
                'type'          => 'sans-serif',
            ),
        );

        return apply_filters( 'et_builder_google_fonts', $google_fonts );
    }
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

Late answer - but I'll bet it's helpful to someone as i still couldn't find an answer to this anywhere today:

To add a custom font to the Divi theme (i'm on V3) font selector dropdowns, you'll need to follow the following steps:

Add your webfont folder to the Divi theme folder eg:
Divi/webfonts

Then reference it from header.php before the closing head tag eg:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $template_directory_uri; ?>/webfonts/customfontname.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
```

Now, in both: themes/Divi/includes/builder/core.php **and** themes/Divi/epanel/custom_functions.php
- find the following line:

```
$google_fonts = array(
```

and add your font after it, as per the other fonts listed - eg:

```
'customfontname'             => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'sans-serif',
        ),
```

This worked a charm for me. The font should be usable and also should appear in the Font selection dropdowns in the Divi Editor with the other google fonts.

**Note:** I know this should be done via a child theme and will be overwritten with a Divi theme update but my php and wordpress-fu is too poor to work out how to manage this just yet.

Answer (score 0):

Divi is a commercial WordPress theme that not everyone has access to, so we don't know the particulars of how the theme is designed; so this is the wrong place to ask, and you should to ask Divi theme support for help. You bought the theme, and support is included in the cost.

Their advice will probably include making a child theme; see [Child Themes « WordPress Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) And/or possibly a plugin to make CSS (and font) changes easy, such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/

Comment: The fact that is commercial does not mean that it doesn't deserve a better answer. Yes, adding via CSS is an option, but he is asking about adding it to the dropdown of font selections. I am looking for the same.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming that you have the latest version update of Divi):

Go to Appearance -> Customize -> General Settings -> Typography

You should see what is in the screenshot below. From there you can change the header and body font

:) Hope this helps

[Screenshot for Typography](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRmif.png)